# different post-class when template is loaded via ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, post-class

my **event-item.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The event template
 */ 
?>

<li>
    <article id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php echo event_canceled($post) ? post_class('wrapper canceled') : post_class('wrapper'); ?>>
```

This leads to this …

```
<article id="event-168" class="post-168 type-wr_event status-publish hentry wrapper wr_event schoenebuecher">
```

However when loading this event-item.php template via ajax the custom-post-type class of `wr_event` is not added.

Anyone an idea why that could happen or what could lead to it?

**Update:**

Ajax:

```
$.get(
    ajax.url, 
    {
        'action': 'get_event_list',
        'order' : 'DSC',
    }, 
    function( response, status ) {
        $('ul.event-items').append(response);
        }
);
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');

function theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/min.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );
    wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'ajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_event_list', 'get_event_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_event_list', 'get_event_list');

function get_event_list( $latest = true, $order = 'ASC', $return = false, $year = NULL, $cat = '' ) {
```

Now I got rid of my  tag that embeds my script in the header.php file. 
The admin-ajax and the embeded script works however doesn't change anything at the behaviour, still no `wr_event` in the post-class.

Comment: How are you loading the template? Could you add your code?

Comment: Updated my question with ajax and function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this format:

#### FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
function theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'ajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function ajax_callback() {
     get_event_list();
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax', 'ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax', 'ajax_callback');
```

#### AJAX:

```
$.get(
    ajax.url, 
    {
        'action': 'ajax',
        'order' : 'DSC',
    }, 
    function( response, status ) {
        $('ul.event-items').append(response);
        }
);
```

You may use this line to explicitly include the `wr_event` class:

```
 <article id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php echo event_canceled($post) ? post_class('wrapper canceled wr_event') : post_class('wrapper wr_event'); ?>>
```

and also add `die();` at the end of the template file to avoid the zero displayed.

Comment: Can you elobrate on that? I updated my question and now use `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script`, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, however still no luck. I have everything exactly like you suggested and the ajax-reload still works. However still no luck with the post-class.

Comment: But I don't know why all other classes work. It's just the class of the custom-post-type that is missing. There is even the class `type-wr_event` but not the `wr_event`?

Comment: You may explicitly include that class. Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that, i just thought there might be a better solution. Thank you anyway. One last question, after every reload of the list items I also get a "0" inserted -> http://cl.ly/TO3N Do you happen to know why? There is no 0 in any template or whatsoever I already checked.

Comment: You have to put `die();` at the end of the file.

Comment: hmm, `die()` is weird in this case, cause this template is looped in the middle of the page, in this case the footer won't get rendered.

Comment: Then you should use a custom ajax template. If your template is `content-a.php`, then copy it in your child theme and rename it with `content-a-ajax.php`, add put `die();` at the end and call this template.